# How to find contours from a Sobel edge detection image

Tags: python, opencv, contour, edge-detection, sobel

I am doing this to apply Sobel edge detection to an image

```
# Sobel edge detection
grad_x = cv2.Sobel(blurred_image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
grad_y = cv2.Sobel(blurred_image, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
grad_magnitude = np.sqrt(grad_x ** 2 + grad_y ** 2)
sobel_edges_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_magnitude)
```

I am able to view it in a window and it looks great, as a next step I am trying to find the contours in the image but I am having trouble with the image format

```
# Apply thresholding to the Sobel gradient magnitude
_, sobel_binary = cv2.threshold(sobel_edges_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Ensure sobel_binary is a single-channel 8-bit image
if len(sobel_binary.shape) != 2 or sobel_binary.dtype != np.uint8:
    raise ValueError("sobel_binary is not in the expected format. It should be a single-channel 8-bit image.")

# Find contours in the binary image
sobel_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(sobel_binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Does anyone know how to go about finding contours after sobel edge detection was applied?

Comment: What is wrong with the `cv2.findContours` call you are using now?  What does the result look like?  Maybe you need to threshold first?

Comment: Perhaps you need to threshold the Sobel image before finding contours.  But why would you do a Sobel to get contours. Why not just threshold your input and then get contours.

Comment: For example, for input image {0,0,0,50,50,50,255,255,255},
thresholding this input will be likes as {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1},
but thresholding edge magnitude can be as { 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}. Not same.